# How to save an AsyncStorage to the state in the react native

Tags: react-native

I'm new in the react native and I'm developing a restaurant app. and I want to implement a buy basket! The customers select foods and foods add to the basket.

Now I want to save each food and its properties in a AsyncStorage and get that in the basket component. my food and its properties are food name, food id, food count and food cost. the key for each food is food name. (key for AsyncStorage).

I want to save the food array in the AsyncStorage and get that in a basket component and then save AsyncStorage to state.
this is my code for saving array in the AsyncStorage :

```
var key=this.state.myfoodName;
var info=[{id : myid,foodName : myfoodName, count : mycount, cost: mycost}];
var myjson=await JSON.stringify(info);
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(key , myjson);
```

and in the basket component, I want to save the AsyncStorage into the state!
and the code for do that is:

```
componentDidMount(){
    AsyncStorage.getAllKeys((err, keys) => {
        keys.map((key,keys)=>{
            AsyncStorage.getItem(key,(error,result)=>{
                    let myresult= JSON.parse(result);
                    console.warn(myresult);  // each key is a food that customer has added to the basket.and i want to save each that to the state.
                    this.setState({

                    baskets: myresult
                    });


            });

            })});
```

the baskets state is:

```
baskets:[{
            id:'',
            foodName:'',
            count:0,
            cost:''
        }]
```

and in a flatlist, I display baskets state.

Problems:

1-when I run this code I can't see the basket list! now I want to know where I have a mistake? I think my array was not correct.

2-I can't save all of asyncstorages to the baskets state. how can I do that?
for example our customer adds 2 foods to the basket. how can I save all of foods in the baskets state and then display that?

Thank advance.

Comment: it seems you added only one item to AsyncStorage. and in this case, it's difficult to save all items. so I think when you add a new item, first fetch the existing items from AsyncStorage, and merge them with the new item, finally, you need to save them.

Comment: You can store it using `JSON.stringify(value)` to any key and use `JSON.parse` to retrieve it

Answer (score 2):

You can have a key named basket of type array.
To add an item in basket:-

1. Get the basket array from asyncstorage.
2. Push the item to basket array.
3. Update the basket array in asyncstorage .

```js
async addItemToBasket(item) {
  let basketItems = await this.getBasketItems();
  console.log("Current basket", basketItems);
  basketItems.push(item);
  console.log("Updated basket", basketItems);
  await AsyncStorage.setItem(
    "basket", 
    JSON.stringify(basketItems)
  );
}

async getBasketItems() {
  let currentBasket = await AsyncStorage.getItem("basket");
  console.log("currentBasket", currentBasket);
  return currentBasket ? JSON.parse(currentBasket) : [];
}
   
// calling addItemToBasket to add item.
this.addItemToBasket({
  id: "345",
  foodName: "pizza",
  count: 1,
  cost: "150"
});

this.addItemToBasket({
  id: "346",
  foodName: "Burger",
  count: 2,
  cost: "100"
});


// calling getBasketItems
componentDidMount() {
  this.getBasketItems()
  .then((basket)=> this.setState({basket: basket}))
   /* here basket will be:  
     [{ id: "345",
        foodName: "pizza",
        count: 1,
        cost: "150"
      },
      {
        id: "346",
        foodName: "Burger",
        count: 2,
        cost: "100"
      }]
    */
}
```